# Karma + Jasmine + nano.jar : how to configure?

Tags: java, javascript, applet, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm using grunt with karma and jasmine for unit tests.

I want to use the `nano.jar` java applet to test timing of some code (as seen on [benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/)).

But I can't figure out how to tell karma to load the html of the applet to the page.

```
<applet code="nano" archive="nano.jar"></applet>
```

I read about fixtures in karma and also about jasmine-jquery fixtures but I can't seem to get them to work.

currently I have this karma.conf:

```
config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      {pattern: '../tests/fixtures/bla.htm', watched: true, served: true, included: false},
      '../tests/**/*.js'
    ]
}
```

And this in `bla.htm`:

```
<applet code="nano" archive="nano.jar"></applet>
```

And this in my test file:

```
describe("testing perf", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/tests/fixtures';
        loadFixtures('bla.htm');
    });

    it("lalala", function() {
        // use nanoseconds here
    });
});
```

But for some reason jasmine-jquery throws a 404 exception when trying to load `base/tests/fixtures/bla.htm`

- How can this be done?
- I would prefer a solution using only karma, I used jasmine-jquery only because I had no success with just karma.